# Version conflict: The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In my .NET Application I am referencing the same Dll in two different versions. When trying to Register the exported implementation of a interface I get the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'MyLoadedDll, Version=15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d29ec89bac048f84' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

My project structure is the following:

MainProgram:

```
var catalag = new DirectoryCatalog($".", $"*MyProject1.dll");
// ...
var builder = new Autofac.ContainerBuilder();
builder.RegisterComposablePartCatalog(catalog);
```

MyProject1:

> Uses MyLoadedDll Version=15.0.0.1

MyProject2:

> Uses MyLoadedDll Version=17.0.0.0

When I clean my bin directory and start the application with the DirectoryCatalog of "MyProject1.dll" it is working.

Without cleaning and changing the string $"*MyProject1.dll" to $"*MyProject2.dll" the builder throws an exception with the given message.

After cleaning and starting the Application with the $"*MyProject2.dll" string again it's working.

Is there a configuration missing to handle the simple existence of two Dlls with two different versions?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/file-schema/runtime/bindingredirect-element

Comment: This doesnt help me much, because I dont want to map the Version 15.0.0.1 to 17.0.0.0. I want to let my code decide which Dll will be used.

Comment: Maybe you can refer [reference two different versions of the same component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/compiler-options/inputs#references).